# How do I prepare for a 10K in one week's time?

Tags: running, training, tracking

I need to prepare for a 10K in a week. This is my first 10K and till now I can only run 4K continuously.

I have problems of acidity which affects my run every other week once.  How do I get ahead of all this? and still manage to complete the 10K. I really wish to do that.

Comment: A 10k is not a marathon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [Galloway Run-Walk](http://www.jeffgalloway.com/training/run-walk/) program.

The harsh reality is that in a week, if you can only run 4k continuously right now, you will not be able to run 10k in a week. Your best bet if you really want to do it, is some sort of the above, where you run 1k, walk .5k, etc. Get used to the idea that you WILL be walking if you go ahead and do the 10k.

If you try to run the entire thing, you WILL cramp, you will most likely be miserable, and end up walking a large portion anyway (If you manage to finish).

Be smart, and you can finish the 10k in relative comfort. Then you can start working on building up endurance for future events.

Comment: I'm in the middle of a 10K right now and I'm cramping up, how can I finish without walking? --sent from my iPhone

Comment: Hey!Thank you @JohnP .
Just to update, I completed a 10.5KM run-walk today morning. Of which I completed 7KM in 56 mins of which 6KM was running.Rest 3.5 KM were a walk.

I have been Run-walking 4KM every other day since Jan 2013. The last few weeks I've started tracking and going for longer runs.
I feel high spirited for the marathon. I hope I can make it.

Comment: @RohanGada - Cool! Just to point out though, there is a big difference between a 10k and a marathon. A marathon is a little over 40k in distance. :)

Comment: Yeah,I do know that. Thanks :)
Should I scale up every day from now?increase the run length I mean

Comment: You shouldn't increase every day. No more than 5% or so every couple weeks for total run distance.

Comment: You run and walk at what speeds? I'm not a expert but i think that if you really want to finish running only you must run at a slower pace. I can walk without get tired 7km/h. I can run a lot at 9km/h, but only a few minutes at 14km/h. You could walk-run-walk-run too, may not be faster but will take you longer

Comment: And the total running distance should not be your goal. Focus on being able to run faster for a longer time without getting tired. Do a 5km race at say 8km/h. Then focus slowly being able to run at 10km/h without getting super tired. The ideal velocity is the one you can sustain consistently and without getting tired. Push this slowly

Comment: Thank you for the support! I completed my first 10K marathon today. Timed at '0:58:47. I realised it's more of a mental block at times.