# Optimizing 10k finishing time until April 3rd

Tags: running, running-training-plan

Today, I won a ticket to a local 10k (6.2 miles) event and now I would like to participate. I've been casually running for ~5 years in regular intervals (~2x/week), but didn't run for at least 3 months.

In the last 5 years I casually attended this event 3x with a time slightly below an hour. However, this time I'd like to train a lot harder.

My goal would be to run the distance in approximate 50 minutes on April 3rd.

Is this doable? Sorry, I know that's a very fuzzy question. What type of training should I do to minimize the 10.5km time?

---

There are two similar posts. However, the post below answered my question perfectly.

Comment: You should remove the marathon tag and replace with a more suitable one.
10k and marathon are far from the same

Comment: Not duplicates, but close: [This question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-do-i-prepare-for-a-10k-in-one-weeks-time) and [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/how-can-i-train-to-run-a-sub-45-minute-10k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With only a month to go before your target event, and not having been running for the last 3 months you are going to have difficulty getting into really good shape.
Generally when training for any event it takes a few months of basic training followed by a few months of more specialised training to get the best results.

However, that doesn't stop you from trying your best with the time you have.  I would suggest the following:

- Get out and run 3 times per week, 4 times if you feel you are recovering well
- 2 to 3 longer runs (45-60 mins) at slightly slower than your target pace
- One shorter run (~30 mins) with hard 5 minute intervals at well above your target pace.

The longer runs are the priority to get miles in the legs, but going slowly enough to not build too much fatigue.  If the distance is no problem to you, then you will feel physically and mentally confident to push the pace on race day.

The one shorter session is to build your speed and high end fitness which will help trim off those few minutes you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these hints. I'm giving this schedule a try. I will post the results. :) Thank you!